# pthread_join() unexpected results

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm having trouble understanding the pthread_join() function because of the results I am getting.

If pthread_join() is supposed to pause the calling thread until the thread of the given thread id finishes it's job then why does the following code not do *Thread 1* work first then do *Thread 2* work. They are both happening concurrently.

If I take out the two pthread_join() lines (from main) the program terminates and nothing happens. Does this mean the *main thread* is the calling process of both join functions and it is the *main thread* who is waiting for the other two newly created threads to finish?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2(void*);

int main()
{

    /* 
        How to Compile
         gcc -c foo
         gcc -pthread -o foo foo.o
    */

    printf("\n\n");

    int rc;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    /* Create two thread --I took out error checking for clarity*/
    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL)
    pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, &thread1)

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

    printf("\n\n");
    exit(0);
}

void *functionCount1()
{

    printf("\nFunction 1");
        sleep(5);
    printf("\nFunction 1");

    return(NULL);
}

void *functionCount2(void* argument)
{

    //pthread_t* threadID = (pthread_t*) argument;

    //pthread_join(*threadID, NULL);

    printf("\nFunction 2");
        sleep(5);
    printf("\nFunction 2");

    return(NULL);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Output with `sleep` commented out:

[image]

Can someone explain why pthread_join is not doing what the documentation leads you to believe?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. It's doing exactly what the documentation leads you to believe. Why would you expect that calling `pthread_join` will pause any thread other than the thread calling it?

Comment: 'Does this mean the main thread is the the calling process of both join functions and it is the main thread who is waiting for the other two newly created threads to finish?' Yes.

Comment: Your `void *functionCount1()` is not a valid thread procedure, it must take a single parameter of type `void*`; doing otherwise is Undefined Behavior (which might appear to work for now, but it could be silently corrupting memory, and it may break horribly in future versions of your OS).

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield Thanks that is good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if `pthread_join()` is supposed to pause the calling *process* until the thread of the given thread id finishes it's job...

That is not quite correct: `pthread_join()` is supposed to pause the calling *thread*, not the calling *process*. Since you are calling `pthread_join()` from the thread running your `main` function, the other two threads are allowed to proceed concurrently, i.e. the way they do in your example.

The reason the code that you commented out does not work is that you are passing a pointer to `pthread_t`, but then you cast it to plain `pthread_t` inside the thread running function (i.e. `pthread_t*` becomes `pthread_t`). Fixing this problem should allow your code to produce the results that you expect:

```
void *functionCount2(void* argument)
{
    pthread_t *threadID = (pthread_t*) argument;
    pthread_join(*threadID, NULL);
    printf("\nFunction 2");
    sleep(5);
    printf("\nFunction 2");
    return(NULL);
}
```

In addition, you should remove `pthread_join( thread1, NULL);` from your `main` function, because the results of multiple simultaneous calls to `pthread_join()` specifying the same target thread are undefined.

Comment: Ok so my assumption was right that its the main thread calling those two lines. So shouldn't I be able to uncomment the two lines in my thread 2 function and have thread 2 wait on thread 1?

Comment: @Mr.Tea There's really no such thing as a "main thread". All threads are essentially equal. The only thing that's special is returning from `main`.

Comment: @Mr.Tea See the update for the reason why the code that you commented out does not do what it should (you are doing the type cast incorrectly.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I updated my post again (really sorry I keep doing that to you) but the output after the fix was still concurrent, your answer did resolve the `sleeping` issue where I had to exit with `ctr + z`.

Comment: @Mr.Tea You are better off asking a new question  - right now it is **very** hard to figure out what you are actually asking, and what your code looks like now - especially since you didn't post it.

Comment: I can ask a new question. I have the full code posted though.

Comment: @Mr.Tea Please do that in the future, instead of changing an existing question that much. Your code now calls pthread_join on thread1 2 places, one in main and one in functionCount2, which you can't do - only 1 thread at a time can wait for another.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently writing a question on that part. Maybe I should stop if you just answered it partially.